# the images aren't displaying when pressing the button

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <head>   
    <script type="javascript/css">
      var die1Image,die2Image,die3Image,die4Image;
      function start(){
        var button=document.getElementById("rollButton");
        button.addEventListener("click",rollDice,false);
        die1Image=document.getElementById("die1");
        die2Image=document.getElementById("die2");
        die3Image=document.getElementById("die3");
        die4Image=document.getElementById("die4");
      }
      function rollDice(){
        setImage(die1Image);
        setImage(die2Image);
        setImage(die3Image);
        setImage(die4Image);
      }
      function setImage(dieImg){
        var dieValue=Math.floor(1+Math.random()*6);
        dieImg.setAttribute("src","die"+dieValue+".png");
        dieImg.setAttribute("alt","die image with "+dieValue+" spot(s)");
      }
      window.addEventListener("load",start,false);
    </script>
</head>
```

```
  <body>
    <form action="#">
      <input id="rollButton" type="button" value="Roll Dice">
    </form>
    <ol>
      <li><img id="die1" src="blank.png" alt="die 1 image"></li>
      <li><img id="die2" src="blank.png" alt="die 2 image"></li>
      <li><img id="die3" src="blank.png" alt="die 3 image"></li>
      <li><img id="die4" src="blank.png" alt="die 4 image"></li>
    </ol>
  </body>
```

whenever I click the roll button, the blank.png photos stay and die photos don't display in their places. the die images are named (die1.png->die6.png) correctly.

Comment: `type="javascript/css"` isn’t a valid JS MIME type. The entire `<script>` just won’t be executed. Remove it.

Comment: I was going to write "text/javascript". worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script type="text/javascript">` and not `"javascript/css"`

Comment: When using HTML5, the `type` attribute is optional. The MIME type `text/javascript` is the default.